# Can we define a function into another function?

Tags: c, function, static-methods

```
int main()
{

  static int fun(){}
  return 0;
}
```

** If we define a function into another then why this code is giving following error:**

*Error: invalid storage class for function ‘fun’*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not support nested functions, simple as that.

To answer the question in comment about *gcc* non-standard nested functions and `static` keyword: as explained in the [*gcc* manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) (link credit to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651356/1717300)):

> A nested function always has no linkage. Declaring one with extern or static is erroneous.

In other words, `static` keyword does not work, because it is explicitly documented to be invalid syntax, because it can not mean what people would expect it to mean.

---

For comparison, standard C++ has the workaround of being able to define class/struct member functions along with the class/struct also inside a function. And C++11 has proper lambda syntax too. But no such things in standard C.

Comment: I want to know why it is working without static keyword?
what is problem with static?

Comment: @user3386914 Edited the answer to cover that

Comment: Can u explain function linkage?

Comment: @user3386914 `extern` linkage means, the the symbol (like a function name) is visible to other translation units (.c files which produce .o files when compiled), and if a function with same name is defined in two translation units, linker will give error (unless they're declared `inline` too). `static` linkage means, symbol is not visible to other translation units, so for example a static function defined in foo.c can't be called for bar.c by its name, and both foo.c and bar.c can have a static function with same name without problems, because each sees their own function only.

Comment: @user3386914 and a *gcc* nested function is neither `extern` nor `static`, it is in the local scope of the containing function.

Answer (score 3):

This is called "nested function". It's not supported in C. Some compilers, such as [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html), offer it as language extension. You do not need the `static` keyword though.

Comment: Read also the wikipages on [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) and [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), since they are relevant.